# adding and displaying favorite names list using jquery/ajax without database

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic

using my website people can search any names in world. users can add their particular name to favorite list. each user can see their favorite names list in another page(names those added by user in one session). can you suggest a best method to do this using jquery/ajax.
Thankz.

Comment: how are u storing the favorite list , what is your database structure ?

Comment: @user1537158: He says `without database`

Comment: ooh ok so if not a database , you store it in a file ,array , how ! ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [local storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute) to save the data. It works as easy as this:

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
localStorage.getItem('key'); // returns 'value'
```

You could save the names using an incrementing key:

```
localStorage.setItem('name-' + (localStorage.length + 1).toString(), 'favName');
// Names stored as 'name-0', 'name1', ...
```

And then, to retrieve the list:

```
var names = new Array();

if (localStorage) {
    if (localStorage.length) {
       for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
           names[i] = localStorage.getItem('name-' + i.toString());
       }
    } else {
       names[0] = 'You have no favorite names stored';
    }
}
```

There are some plugins that provide fallbacks on browsers that don't support web storage (Even on ie6), like [totalStorage](https://github.com/jarednova/jquery-total-storage) or [jstorage](http://www.jstorage.info/).

Comment: yes, this worked..... thank you scumah,  we can learn about basic html5  local storage here.... http://paperkilledrock.com/2010/05/html5-localstorage-part-one/

Comment: nice @user1693763, I'm glad it helped :D