# How to make a "Favorites" page in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, jquery-mobile

I'm new to coding in Jquery Mobile (I just stared a couple of months ago).  I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to create a "ADD TO FAVORITES" function for a Jquery mobile app.

I looked into HTML5 local storage however most of the examples I have found only work with only one value.

There is this one example that I found that adds multiple values but I'm not sure how to use it (like I said I'm fairly new to this)

[adding and displaying favorite names list using jquery/ajax without database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560992/adding-and-displaying-favorite-names-list-using-jquery-ajax-without-database)

For example Here's exactly what I am looking to do

1) I have several unique HTML pages (ex. location_1, location_2, ... location_n) and each page will have a "Add to Favorites" button.
2) If the person chooses to add the location as a favorite, the button on the page should be disabled and a link to the page should be saved in the "Favorites" page.
3) If a person removes the location from the "Favorites" page, the icon button should be enabled on the page that had its link deleted.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div data-role="page" id="Location1">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
         <h1>Location 1</h1> 
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>My page footer</h1>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div data-role="page" id="Favorites">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
         <h1>Favorites</h1> 
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <ul id="favorite_links"></ul>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>My page footer</h1>
    </div>

</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Follow this Todo example to further understand how local-storage is used for saving, displaying and deleting data. You will only need to grab some of code to fit into your App --- http://www.amitpatil.me/todo-app-for-iphone-ipad-using-jquery-mobile-and-web-storage/